# Justification of optimal value of an objective function of an LPP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I was first asked to solve the following linear program:

$Z_{max}=2x+3y$

subject to the constraints

$\begin{align*}
&2x+7y\ge22\\  
&x+y\ge6  \\
&5x+y\ge10 \\ 
&x,y\ge0
\end{align*}$

I solved it graphically and found that the feasible region is unbounded. Next I was asked to justify:

> Any objective function of the form $lx-my$ (both $l, m$ of same sign) has finite maximum or infinite minimum subject to the constraints of the above LPP.

Since the feasible region is unbounded above, so infinite maximum is a possible case. Again since the region is bounded below, so the minimum value is finite and corresponds to the vertex $(4,2)$.

I don't get the sense of this question. Neither "Finite maximum" nor "Infinite minimum" is a possibility subject to the given constraints. Because here maximum is infinite and minimum is finite.
Nevertheless if the statement is valid, what would be correct justification?

Comment: Where does this LPP come from?

Comment: Minimum makes sense here: $\{14,\{x\to 4,y\to 2\}\}$

Comment: @gpmath but minimum is finite here